# How did Hades enter camp half blood?

Tags: percy-jackson

In *Percy Jackson: Sea of Monsters*, Percy is narrating that Camp Half Blood is the only safe haven for 'our kind', see 1:20:

But in *Percy Jackson: The Lightning Thief* we see Hades enter the camp and throw fire balls around.

Being that Hades is not a half blood, how does he enter the camp?

Comment: Your Youtube link has gone dead. Might want to fix that or remove it.

Comment: Did Hades himself actually enter the camp, or was it just a a projection of some sort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The films are wildly inconsistent from the books but according to the books the only thing stopping bad stuff entering is Thalia's spirit trapped in a pine tree. I assume Thalia doesn't have the strength to stop a god. Furthermore half bloods can allow over creatures to enter. Chiron mentions it in book 1 and Anabeth demonstrates it in book two allowing Tyson into camp. It is possible Luke allowed Hades to appear in the camp in order to get Percy to leave camp and go after Hades. Despite these security weaknesses Camp Half Blood is still the safest place for half bloods in the films as it keeps out monsters and has a small army of demigods there to fight anything that gets through.

Answer (score 4):

The barrier that Zeus erected around the Camp protects it from monters who want to harm the half-blood children. That's fine for things like cyclops and minotaur.

But Hades is a god himself, and Zeus' brother. That implies that Hades is nearly as strong as Zeus himself. If anyone in the universe could get past Zeus's barrier, it would be his brothers. Beyond that, Hades didn't really want to hurt anyone in *Lightning Thief*, he wanted to scare them. He wanted the thief *alive*, so he could get the bolt back.

Answer (score 0):

The movies are very inaccurate and far from what actually happened but with the given information, Hades can indeed easily enter Camp Half Blood.

1. Hades is the god of the Underworld so, technically, he is able to pop up anywhere in the world, withstanding barriers such as Camp Half Blood because it doesn't any run deeper into the ground. It is only for the surface so, it would make sense that Hades can come in via the Underworld.
2. A second way he could pass through the barrier is simply because he is a god. In the second movie, Poseidon brought Tyson to the camp. Tyson, being a cyclops cannot pass through the barrier without the help of an immortal deity, even though he is a child of Poseidon. If any children of the gods could enter, CHB would be most likely run over by Cyclopes, being children of Poseidon. I think if you are either half god or fully god, you may pass through the barrier.
3. Hades can pass through the barrier because he has the power to. Evidence shows (in Camp Half Blood Confidential) that the barrier

> Powered by the strongest Mist and guaranteed to repel even the most determined monsters* and noisiest mortals.
>
> *Some restrictions apply. With invading armies and giant, hostile animated statues, results may vary.

This "hostile animated statue" is the one and only Terminus. He is the Roman god of boundaries and has no Greek counterpart. This shows that gods, Greek and Roman are able to pass through the barrier, according to Pete the Palikos.

Those are some ways Hades might have passed through the barrier.

Comment: I believe the statue actually refers to Colossus Neronis from The Hidden Oracle. It, unlike Terminus, is "giant" and "hostile."